# Upsert/on conflict with serial primary key

Tags: sql, postgresql

The upsert works using on conflict but the datatype of id is serial meaning I want to have it auto-generated/incremented. If I do the insert without specifying id the insert works fine.

The problem I have is combining the two. To get the key auto incremented I do not pass the id into the insert but if I do not pass id then the update will never fire. I cannot pass null to id as it is non-null field.

In below example - I run the query first time and it does insert and second time it does update but I cannot figure out how to pass 'nothing' to insert so the identity key still works on insert. I can put DEFAULT in the insert but then I cannot pass a real id value if there is one.

```
CREATE TABLE public.upsert_test
(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('upsert_test_id_seq'::regclass),
    name character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    description character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT upsert_test_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

INSERT INTO upsert_test (id, name, description)
VALUES (1, 'thing1', 'test')
on conflict (id)
do update set (name , description) = ('thing_updated','test-updated')   
where upsert_test.id = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change your query to use sequence functions like:

```
INSERT INTO upsert_test (id, name, description)
VALUES ((select nextval('upsert_test_id_seq')), 'thing1', 'test')
on conflict (id)
do update set (name , description) = ('thing_updated','test-updated')   
where upsert_test.id = (select currval('upsert_test_id_seq'));
```

Note this may not be threadsafe, for eg if second call to this sql is executed before `select currval('upsert_test_id_seq')` in first call, then the update may fail in first query.

**Update after more information from op**

You can change the query to like this:

```
INSERT INTO upsert_test (id, name, description)
VALUES (COALESCE(:YOUR_ID_PARAM, (select nextval('upsert_test_id_seq'))), 'thing1', 'test')
on conflict (id)
do update set (name , description) = ('thing_updated','test-updated')   
where upsert_test.id = :YOUR_ID_PARAM;
```

Note I added the [coalesce](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-coalesce/) function so if your parameter is null then use sequence nextval. Also, the update now also uses your parameter.

Comment: Thanks for response.   I think I would need to test the variable that is 'id'  before submitting to the query and if it is null then I would change it to the nextval function as you suggested.  I was hoping to not have to manipulate the id value but this seems like it will work out. thanks

Comment: It wasn't clear to me you wanted a null check, I updated the answer.

Comment: Yes - that works well.  I tried VALUES (COALESCE(:YOUR_ID_PARAM, (Default)), 'thing1', 'test') but it doesn't seem to like default in this context.  thanks