# How to upsert with serial primary key

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a stored procedure to perform an upsert. However the conflict condition never runs, passing an existing ID always causes it to create a new record.

```
create or replace function upsert_email(v_id bigint, v_subject character varying)
  returns bigint
language plpgsql
as $$
declare
  v_id bigint;
begin
  insert into emails
    (id, subject)
    values (coalesce(v_id, (select nextval('serial'))), v_subject)
  on conflict(id)
    do update set (subject) = (v_subject) where emails.id = v_id
  returning id into v_id;

  return v_id;
end;
$$;
```

When running `select upsert_email(6958500, 'subject');` which is a record that exists, it always creates a new record instead.

I have already looked at: [Upsert/on conflict with serial primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51708197/upsert-on-conflict-with-serial-primary-key) which is the most similar question and is what my SQL is modeled on, however I haven't been able to get it to work.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `(select nextval('serial')))` can be simplified to `nextval('serial')`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I thought the coalesce handled that so that when an ID is passed it never moves on to generating the serial?

Comment: You don't need the `select` at that position, you can use `nextval()` directly: `coalesce(v_id, nextval('serial'))`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks, I've updated that in my system now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, idiot of the year award goes to me.

I'm taking a parameter called v_id, then immediately overwrite it in the declare with a v_id; They should be named 2 different things:

```
create or replace function upsert_email(v_id bigint, v_subject character varying)
  returns bigint
language plpgsql
as $$
declare
  v_return_id bigint;
begin
  insert into emails
    (id, subject)
    values (coalesce(v_id, (select nextval('serial'))), v_subject)
  on conflict(id)
    do update set (subject) = (v_subject) where emails.id = v_id
  returning id into v_return_id;

  return v_return_id;
end;
$$;
```

Comment: This was caused by my practice of using v_ prefix for variables, I should probably come up with a better practice where input variables get a different prefix to declared variables in case they have crossover like in my example above.

Comment: That's why I always prefix parameters with `p_` and local variables with `l_`